# Is there a way to construct a PIVOT's IN clause using a SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, pivot

I want to build a `PIVOT` table, but I may have to use dynamic SQL unless the `IN` clause can be constructed in regular SQL.  I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT x, y, z...
) srcTable
PIVOT
(
    MIN(srcTable.TimesDownloaded) FOR OrganizationName IN (SELECT CONCAT('Download_', OrganizationName) FROM AdamUser GROUP BY OrganizationName)
) pivotTable
```

So when I `SELECT` unique `OrganizationName`s from `AdamUser` and prefix `Download_`, that gives me a table whose row values equal the names of the columns I want.  This is invalid syntax though.  Do I always have to hard-code the `PIVOT` column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T-SQL documentation of the [FROM clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) has this for the  specification:

```
<pivoted_table> ::=  
    table_source PIVOT <pivot_clause> [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
```

```
<pivot_clause> ::=  
        ( aggregate_function ( value_column [ [ , ]...n ])   
        FOR pivot_column   
        IN ( <column_list> )   
    )
```

```
<column_list> ::=  
    column_name [ ,...n ]
```

---

So no, it doesn't allow you to select the column names with a SELECT statement, and yes, you have to "hard-code" the `PIVOT` column names.